# Can a 13 year old in the uk hire an employee?

Tags: united-kingdom, employment

I have a 13 year old child who would like to start a company as a sole trader, can he employ someone as his business idea involves having an employee.

Comment: This feels more a question for the Law stack, although it would need to be about a generic 13-year-old, to avoid being seen as asking for personal legal advice.

Comment: Unless a parent or guardian guarantees it, you cannot force a 13 year old to pay your salary.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is legal issue that goes beyond money issues.